# what is the difference of substitution cost 1 and substitution cost 2 variation in levenstein distance for string matching

Tags: levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison

I am learning fuzzy search, for this, I was reading about Levenshtein distance. I have found 2 variations in substitution operation some sites shows that substitution operation cost is 1, some sites shows that substitution operation cost is 2(insertion+ deletion ). I am a bit of confused which one I should take for implementation. Need a clear concept